# Geometric mean is to arthithmetic mean as arithmetic mean is to what?

Tags: real-analysis, arithmetic, mathematical-modeling

I am interested in a type of "mean" $r$ associated to a set $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ where

$$
e^r=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n e^{a_i}.
$$

I will call this the "? mean" for now

The reason I believe this must have been studied is that if I instead consider $s$ for which

$$
{\rm ln}(s)=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {\rm ln}(a_i),
$$
I get

$$
s=\big(\prod\limits_{i=1}^n a_i\big)^{1/n};
$$

in other words, the geometric mean. So to some extent we have

Geometric mean: Arithmetic mean :: Arithmetic mean : ? mean

Does anyone know what this kind of mean is called?

Comment: That is the last example listed here. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-arithmetic_mean

Comment: If you follow the naming pattern of *root mean square* then you might call it the *logarithm mean exponential* or *LogMeanExp*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geometric mean is the exponential of the arithmetic mean of the logarithms, i.e.

$$ \text{GM}(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = \exp\left(\text{AM}\left(\log a_1,\ldots,\log a_n\right)\right). $$
If you set

$$ \text{AM}(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = \exp\left(\text{UM}\left(\log a_1,\ldots,\log a_n\right)\right) $$

(where $\text{UM}$ stands for *unknown mean*) you get that $\text{UM}$ has the following property:

$$ \text{UM}(b_1,\ldots,b_n) = \log\text{AM}\left(e^{b_1},\ldots,e^{b_n}\right). $$

This is [the mean in the log semiring, which is a smooth maximum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-arithmetic_mean).